# How to write to text field in an msi installer with python?

Tags: python, automation, windows-installer, textfield, autofill

I'm automating the installation of a program with python.

So far I can locate the .msi installer and execute it, and then I can automate all the clicks to go through the installation process.

The thing I'm stuck on is, I can't manage to find a way to fill in the text fields that come up during the installation. For example as your installing a software the installer might prompt you to enter your name, or address etc. How do I do an "autofill" for those text fields by pre-defining strings in my script and inserting them to the text fields as they pop-up?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you do this?  Windows Installer supports silent installation and passing of secure custom public properties.

```
msiexec /I foo.msi /qn SOMEPROPERTY=somevalue
```

[Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)